# how can I make sure emacs always saves edited/created plain text as utf8?

Tags: macos, emacs

I'll be opening txt files created in a lot of different encodings (from before I knew what an encoding was) in emacs. Sometimes they don't display correctly but, as it turns out, 5 seconds of find and replace is usually enough to fix any problem. To minimize future headaches I want all files I use with emacs to be utf-8. **Is there any way to (1) force emacs to display files as if they were utf-8 encoded and/or (2) always save new/and or edited text files with a utf-8 encoding?**

Comment: Have a look at the command `prefer-coding-system`, which will take care of new files.

Comment: If encoding detection fails when opening a file, you can reopen it with a different encoding via `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` (normally bound to `C-x RET r`).

Comment: For saving an open file with another encoding, `set-buffer-file-coding-system` (bound to `C-x RET f`) changes the current buffer enconding. You can check the current encoding on the first symbols on the status bar (1 for latin-1, U for UTF, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

I have this in my `.emacs` (of course I copied from somewhere). I think they are straight forward to understand

```
 (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
 (setq default-file-name-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
 (setq default-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
 (setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix))
 (setq default-sendmail-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
 (setq default-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
(set-locale-environment "en_US.UTF-8")
```

where "en" is the language code, and "US" the country code (which affects paper size, and maybe some other things).  <kbd>C-h f</kbd>`set-locale-environment` for more details.